# URL redirection to be relative from current URL, how?

Tags: html, url, axios

Current URL is, `localhost/admin/banner`.

I have axios usage as

```
axios.post('modifyBannerData', {
...
}
```

When this calls, this function calls `localhost/admin/modifyBannerData`

I expected it to be `localhost/admin/banner/modifyBannerData`

Can you help me on this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The rules for relative paths are:

1. Remove everything after the path
2. Remove everything after the last `/`
3. Append the relative path

It won't produce an extra `/` from nowhere to append after `banner`.

You could do that explicitly (i.e. make the base URL `localhost/admin/banner/`).

Generally, it is safest to use *absolute paths* instead of relative ones.

```
axios.post('/admin/banner/modifyBannerData',
```